# Need to return a value from a do/while and multiple while loops - C

Tags: c, while-loop, cs50

I am trying to build a simple change calculator of sorts. The user inputs an amount of change owed, and then they press return. The value they entered is supposed to be multiplied by 100 first (so that when we round it, the digits are not truncated). The rounding is supposed to turn the float into an int, and then all the math operations (the while loops) should execute, with a single number printing out at end that represents how many coins they were given (i.e. how many quarters, dimes, etc...) The code compiles fine, it prompts the user to input a value, but then when you press return, nothing is executed, and the command line goes back to being blank.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? My guess is the values in the while loops are not getting transferred out of the loop, so they can be used in the next loop. But then I am a very early beginner in C language, and not sure the correct rules for the loops. I tried looking up while loop examples, but nothing really explains exactly how to get a value to carry from one while loop to another. If, in fact, that is the problem. Thanks for your help.

CODE REVISION:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) {

    float change;
    int cents;

    int quarter_count = 0;
    int dime_count = 0;
    int nickel_count = 0;
    int pennies = 0;
    int total_count;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the amount of change you are owed: ");
        change = GetFloat();
        cents = round(change * 100); 
    }
    while (change < 0);
    return cents;

    int quarter = 25;
    while (cents >= quarter)
    {
        cents = cents - quarter;
        quarter_count++;
    }
    return cents;

    int dime = 10;
    while (cents >= dime)
    {
        cents = cents - dime;
        dime_count++;
    }
    return cents;

    int nickel = 5;
    while (cents >= nickel)
    {
        pennies = cents - nickel;
        nickel_count++;
    }
    return pennies;

    total_count = quarter_count + dime_count + nickel_count + pennies;

    printf("%d\n", total_count);

}
```

Comment: I see a lot of unused variables here??

Comment: `getFloat()` is from the cs50 library, basically it takes the user's number input and marks it as a float variable, that I can then use elsewhere in the rest of my code.

Comment: try putting print statements in each of the loops, find where the control flow is getting to.

Comment: Henno, which ones are unused? That did not come up in the compile as an error, and it used to come up, but not anymore.

Comment: Ah, good idea sjeohp.

Comment: Jayesh, that is maybe a good point, i thought i was saying, only to repeat the loop IF the number entered is negative. does it not mean that in my code? because the `do` part of the loop runs once.

Comment: in particular I would print the value of change at the end of the `do` block

Comment: what about second loop `while (cents >= quarter)` if i enter value of `change=10`? it will break?

Comment: Jayesh, not break but it will be skipped (i think)... but omg, you just made me realize, i should be using if statements perhaps, because this doesn't account for smaller amounts... i mean, the variable used for the other loops depends on that 2nd loop, which should not be how it is... thanks! going to change that.

Comment: @Jayesh, I updated my code to accept lesser values of cents, but can I reuse the `cents` variable like that, all the way down my code? I reassign it quite a bit. Is that allowed in while loops and in C? Is my use of `return` correct?

Comment: @NoniA. wrong..you just return  `return cents;` value of `cents` so your program exit from that and not execute code below `return cents;` statement. Looks for my update in answer.

Comment: Ohhh, so when I do a return on a while loop, then the code won't run the code below it? (sorry, where is your updated answer?)

Comment: I took out all the `return cents;` and all the returns but the code still stops before the 2nd loop. :(

Comment: @NoniA. Ohh.. Now you can see my answer.Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After every while loop you put `return` statement so. Code after first `while..loop` meaning less.

Also for third `while..loop` you put condition like `while (cents >= nickel)` but in while loop you dont alter value of `cents`.So it will in infinine loop if `cent` value remain greater then when it reach upto third `while..loop`.

See my updated code.It will do basic functionality which may be you want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) {

    float change;
    int cents;

    int quarter_count = 0;
    int dime_count = 0;
    int nickel_count = 0;
    int pennies = 0;
    int total_count;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the amount of change you are owed: ");
        change = GetFloat();
        cents = round(change * 100); 
    }
    while (change < 0);


    int quarter = 25;

    while (cents >= quarter)
    {
        cents = cents - quarter;
        quarter_count++;
    }

     if (cents <= 0)
      goto done;

    int dime = 10;
    while (cents >= dime)
    {
        cents = cents - dime;
        dime_count++;
    }

   if (cents <= 0)
      goto done;

    int nickel = 5;

    pennies=cents;

    while (pennies >= nickel)
    {
        pennies = pennies - nickel;
        nickel_count++;
    }

done:
    total_count = quarter_count + dime_count + nickel_count + pennies;

    printf("%d\n", total_count);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Jayesh!! Actually I did not even need any of the if statements, simply taking out all the returns ended up working (I realized there was one I forgot!)... but I am curious, why did you put a `return 0;` at the bottom?

Comment: Your `main` is non-void `int main (void)`. It's raise you warning if you not return anything. So it will good to return some value.

Comment: Oh thanks. I am compiling and running in a Terminal, so did not get an error, but good to know in case that comes up in the future. :)